# Why does a left curly brace impact the flalign alignment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, mathtools, flalign

I've a pretty long text commenting several sets of short equations. This leads me to some presentation constraints that I'd like to better handle:

- flush the equation sets to the left (short text in the center of the page is ugly),
- align the equation sets on the '=' sign between sets. This forces me to build on align, alignat or flalign because I can't interrupt an array with (short)intertext (AFAIK),
- I need to begin the equation sets with a left curly brace. I use 'dcases' but never achieved to have it functioning in 'alignat' (AFAIK)

In my MWE, the third example gives the result I expected. However, when I add a left curly brace, LaTeX adds a strange space before the '=' sign. Any idea about where this is coming from?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}    % WARNING: Source UTF8-encoded

\usepackage{amsmath}%,amssymb}
%\usepackage{eqparbox,xintexpr}
\usepackage{mathtools} % dcases

\begin{document}

{\bf'align' means centered on '='}
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 &= \cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) \\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\end{align*}
{\bf'flalign' means flushed to left and aligned on '='}
\begin{flalign*}
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 &= \cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) &\\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \sin(\theta_1+\theta_2) &% Need tailing alignment char to get all the way left
\end{flalign*}
{\bf'flalign' with a compliant indentation}
\begin{flalign*}
\hspace{\parindent}\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 &= \cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) &\\
\hspace{\parindent}\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \sin(\theta_1+\theta_2) &% Need tailing alignment char to get all the way left
\end{flalign*}
{\bf'In 'flalign', curly brackets have an indentation impact on '='?}
\begin{flalign*}% 
\hspace{\parindent}&\begin{dcases}
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2&=\cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2)\\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2&=\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\end{dcases}&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: `\bf` is depreciated. Use `\mathbf` instead.

Comment: the fl in flalign is "full length" not "flush left" `align`, `equation` etc will all set flush left not centred if you use the `fleqn` option to `\documentclass` or `amsmath`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought into the formula....excuse me....very much. :-(

Comment: You are using luainputenc (which you should probably not use) but if you are using luatex you should not use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` either as that forces legacy 8bit fonts. In my answer I kept the T1 encoding (and used pdflatex)

Comment: You should consider to use the environment `cases`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `fleqn` option to get flush left alignment. `dcases` adds a quad space by design, but the package provides `\newcases` to define a similar command without that:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}% flush left equations
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% it is best to avoid this unless you really need it \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}    % WARNING: Source UTF8-encoded

\usepackage{amsmath}%,amssymb}
%\usepackage{eqparbox,xintexpr}
\usepackage{mathtools} % dcases

\makeatletter
% a copy of dcases but without \quad in the second argument
% and with {} at the start of the second column so &= gets relation space like align
\newcases{dcasesnoquad}{}{%
  $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Left aligned alignment
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 &= \cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) \\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\end{align*}

dcases
\[
\begin{dcasesnoquad}
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2&=\cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2)\\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2&=\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\end{dcasesnoquad}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You not need  use the `dcases` for left curly braces. Similar result you can obtain with use of ˙\left{˙ before `aligned` or by use `empheq`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, empheq}
 
\begin{document}
\textbf{With 'align*'}
    \begin{align*}
        \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 - \sin\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) \\
        \sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2)
    \end{align*}

\textbf{With 'aligned'}
\[
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
        \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 - \sin\theta_1 \sin\theta_2   & = \cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2)\\
        \sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2   & = \sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2)
    \end{aligned}\right.  
\]

\textbf{With 'empheq'}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
        \cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2      & = \cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2)\\
        \sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2   & = \sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2)
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show test border)

**Edit:** In the first attempt I miss understood, where the equations should be. Now this is corrected (and by this my answer become more similar to other answers ...)

Comment: I think you dropped a `fleqn` somewhere, your image shows left alignment but the code makes centred

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right. I only add new image and forgot to update code in answer. Thank you for pointing me on this my superficiality.

Answer (score 2):

Two other solutions: one with `empheq` and `flalign*`, and another with the `fleqn`  environment from `nccmath` & `dcases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{empheq} %

\begin{document}
\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{empheq}[left=\hspace{\parindent}\empheqlbrace]{flalign*}%
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2&=\cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) & & \\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2&=\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\end{empheq}

\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\[ \begin{dcases}
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2=\cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) \\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2=\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\end{dcases} \]
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes although alignment on = in the last one is just because coscossinsin is the same width as sincoscossin

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You're right, but if it happened not to be spontaneously aligned, it is always possible to use an `aligned` or even `alignedat` environment – albeit in this case, the solution with `empheq`  would be recommended.

Comment: yes I know (and I know you know:-) just left a comment in case a later reader cuts and pastes but changes the expression.

Comment: That's the way I understood it.