# Align equations with the same spacing

Tags: spacing, equations, align, amsmath

[image]

I can't manage to get the "=" proper spacing. I would like to get LHS = RHS, instead of LHS  = RHS

Code used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
        W &= F \, \Delta x\\
        W &= E_c\\
        F &= m a\\
        x &= x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}a t^2\\
        v &= v_0 + a t
    \end{cases}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: cases adds space, see this answer from earlier today https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566211/why-does-a-left-curly-brace-impact-the-flalign-alignment/566213#566213

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest that you make three changes. First, encase the five equations in an `aligned` environment. Second, since you're not really making use of the machinery of the `cases` environment, replace the `cases` environment with `\left\{ ... \right.`. Third, since you're not making use of the `align*` machinery either, I'd replace the `align*` environment with `\[ ... \]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        W &= F \, \Delta x\\
        W &= E_c\\
        F &= m a\\
        x &= x_0 + v_0 t + \tfrac{1}{2}a t^2\\
        v &= v_0 + a t
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this worked for me:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\makeatletter
% a copy of dcases but without \quad in the second argument
% and with {} at the start of the second column so &= gets relation space like align
\newcases{dcasesnoquad}{}{%
  $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
\makeatother
```